# JavaScript - Calculate combinations from 4 dropdown menus the value between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

helo i find this code here that calculate a price between 2 drop down menus

```
   function getBoostingPrice() {
  var yourLeague = document.getElementById("yourLeague").selectedIndex;
  var desiredLeague = document.getElementById("desiredLeague").selectedIndex;
  var options = document.getElementById("yourLeague").options;

  var totalPrice = 0;
  for (var i = yourLeague; i <= desiredLeague; i++) {
    totalPrice += parseInt(options[i].value);
  }
  var totalCalc = document.getElementById('totalCalc');
  totalCalc.innerHTML = totalPrice.toString();
};
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action=" " id="boostingForm">
    <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn">
      <label>Your League</label>
      <select id="yourLeague">
        <option id="b5" value="5">Bronze V</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">Bronze IV</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">Bronze III</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">Bronze II</option>
        <option id="b1" value="10">Bronze I</option>
        <option id="s5" value="10">Silver V</option>
        <option id="s4" value="10">Silver IV</option>
        <option id="s3" value="10">Silver III</option>
        <option id="s2" value="12">Silver II</option>
        <option id="s1" value="12.5">Silver I</option>
        <option id="g5" value="12.5">Gold V</option>
        <option id="g4" value="12.5">Gold IV</option>
        <option id="g3" value="12.5">Gold III</option>
        <option id="g2" value="15">Gold II</option>
        <option id="g1" value="17.5">Gold I</option>
        <option id="p5" value="20">Platinum V</option>
        <option id="p4" value="20">Platinum IV</option>
        <option id="p2" value="22.5">Platinum III</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum II</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum I</option>
        <option id="d5" value="30">Diamond V</option>
        <option id="d4" value="40">Diamond IV</option>
        <option id="d3" value="55">Diamond III</option>
        <option id="d2" value="80">Diamond II</option>
        <option id="d1" value="160">Diamond I</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn2">
      <label>Desired League</label>
      <select id="desiredLeague">
        <option id="b5" value="5">Bronze V</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">Bronze IV</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">Bronze III</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">Bronze II</option>
        <option id="b1" value="10">Bronze I</option>
        <option id="s5" value="10">Silver V</option>
        <option id="s4" value="10">Silver IV</option>
        <option id="s3" value="10">Silver III</option>
        <option id="s2" value="12">Silver II</option>
        <option id="s1" value="12.5">Silver I</option>
        <option id="g5" value="12.5">Gold V</option>
        <option id="g4" value="12.5">Gold IV</option>
        <option id="g3" value="12.5">Gold III</option>
        <option id="g2" value="15">Gold II</option>
        <option id="g1" value="17.5">Gold I</option>
        <option id="p5" value="20">Platinum V</option>
        <option id="p4" value="20">Platinum IV</option>
        <option id="p2" value="22.5">Platinum III</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum II</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum I</option>
        <option id="d5" value="30">Diamond V</option>
        <option id="d4" value="40">Diamond IV</option>
        <option id="d3" value="55">Diamond III</option>
        <option id="d2" value="80">Diamond II</option>
        <option id="d1" value="160">Diamond I</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    TOTAL: <span id="totalCalc"></span>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" class="orderButton" id="submitOrder" value="Order Now!" onclick="getBoostingPrice();">
</body>

</html>
```

but i want look like this one who calculate the same price with 4 dropdown menus `

```
<head>

  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action=" " id="boostingForm">
    <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn">
      <label>Your League</label>
      <select id="from">
        <option id="b5" value="5">Bronze</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">Silver</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">Gold</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">Platinum</option>

      </select>



      <select id="from1">
        <option id="b5" value="5">V</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">IV</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">III</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">II</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">I</option>

      </select>

       <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn">
      <label>Desire League</label>
      <select id="to">
        <option id="b5" value="5">Bronze</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">Silver</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">Gold</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">Platinum</option>

      </select>



      <select id="to1">
        <option id="b5" value="5">V</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">IV</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">III</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">II</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">I</option>

      </select>

  `
```

and make the same calculations with first code